# sorting an array in decreasing order

Tags: arrays

I have to write a program to open a file that contains 3 columns, each row represents data for a baseball player. the first columns represents the players number, second is times at bat, lastly the third is average hits. I have to sort the players in descending order of average hits. I am having a problem, it orders them in descending order of number times at bat. also the first 3 numbers are not printing out correctly.

here are the first 3 players data

3 5  .400

5   1   .000

9   30  .167

here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
float BattingA[13], At_Bat[13];
int Player_ID[13];

void Sort_Arrays(int ID[], float at_bat[], float average[]);
int main()
{
  int ID[13];
  float at_bat[13], average[13];
  FILE *readfile;
  int i;
if ((readfile = fopen("cubs-batting-ws-ab-avg.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("The file failed to open\n");
}

for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    fscanf(readfile, "%d %f %f", ID + i, at_bat + i, average + i);
    Sort_Arrays(ID, at_bat, average);
}

printf("numbers\n");
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    printf("%d %.0f %.3f \n", ID[i], at_bat[i], average[i]);
}
if (fclose(readfile) == EOF)//close the file.
{
    printf("The file failed to close.\n");
}

return 0;
}

void Sort_Arrays(int ID[], float BattingA[], float AtBat[])
{
int x, y = 13, z;
float New, NewID, NewAtBat;
for (x = 0; x < y; x++)
{
    for (z = x + 1; z < y; z++)
    {
        if (BattingA[x] < BattingA[z])
        {
            NewID = ID[x];
            NewAtBat = AtBat[x];
            New = BattingA[x];

            ID[x] = ID[z];
            AtBat[x] = AtBat[z];
            BattingA[x] = BattingA[z];

            ID[z] = NewID;
            AtBat[z] = NewAtBat;
            BattingA[z] = New;
        }

    }
}
}
```

anything you could do to help i would really appreciate it.
thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments are being passed to the Sort_Arrays function in the wrong order. at_bat is being passed in as the 2nd argument. As Sort_Arrays is written to sort according to the 2nd argument, your arrays are being sorted according to at_bat.

Comment: Ok i see what you are talking about. when I changed it it worked, but there is still an issue. i have total of 13 rows, only 11 of the rows actually sort, 2 are transformed into really long numbers. one of the data points that is having an issue is when the average = 0.000. instead of going to the buttom it goes to the top of the list with the average number being changed to 3116043012715996800000000000000.000

Comment: I figured it out, I accidentally called my function with the read file braces, (just under the fscanf). after i moved it outside those brackets it all worked perfectly fine.  Thank you Noah Sherrill, you saved my but.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It's often useful just to have a fresh set of eyes after a while :).